# jquery change not working in html select option

Tags: jquery

I have a `select option` like this.

```
 <select class="form-control" id="province_id" name="province_id">
```

I used whatever you said but it didn't work

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#provinces_id').change(function(){
            alert('Hello');
        }) ;
```

or

```
 $(document).on('change', '#provinces_id', function() {
     alert('Hello');
 });
```

The above code doesn't work. When I click on #clicker, it doesn't alert and and it doesn't hide. I checked the console and I get no errors. I also checked to see if JQuery was loading and indeed it is. So not sure what the issue is. I also did a document ready function with an alert and that worked so not sure what I am doing wrong. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the selector.

The `<select>` has an ID `province_id` (singular), but your jQuery selector uses `provinces_id` (plural).

**Solution**: Unify the IDs.

Comment: I changed this `province_id` to `xxx`. But it did not work.

Comment: Where's #clicker in your code? And like Petr mentioned, unify ID's.